# Shell script in Ubuntu raspberry pi 2

Tags: scripts, raspberrypi

I am writing the shell script in Ubuntu for raspberry pi 2. Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh

source /home/ubuntu/ros_package/devel/setup.bash
roslaunch uvc_camera camera_node.launch &

#Open new tab
WID=$(xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"| awk '{print $5}')
xdotool windowfocus $WID
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
wmctrl -i -a $WID

source /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
rosrun hybrid_tracking ir_track
```

I have few problems in this script:

1. It doesn't recognize the source command.
2. When I put & behind roslaunch, it still log a lot of output and the following command failed to execute.
3. I expected to open a new tab and run the rest of script in another tab but it won't.

Comment: `source` is a bash-ism: since the file you're attempting to source also appears to be a bash file, you should change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As steeldriver noted, `#!/bin/sh` refers to `dash` shell, and `dash` *does not have source command*. You can change your top line to `#!/bin/bash` to call `bash` instead of `dash`.

Alternatively, you can change `source` to `.`  , so line would be `. /home/ubuntu/ros_package/devel/setup.bash` . However, you're trying to source `bash` file. That means, there may be non-portable code lines there, and sourcing that file may fail

For `roslaunch uvc_camera camera_node.launch &` you need to change it to `roslaunch uvc_camera camera_node.launch 2>&1 > /dev/null &` so that the output of that command is not displayed.

Note also , that you should quote your variables ( like `"$WID"` ) to prevent word splitting  ( unless you do want contents of `$WID` to be treated as separate items , or if there is no separate words there).